# ip domain name/FQDN using dig

Tags: domain, dig

When I do a dig on a hostname, in our network, it doesn't not give me the IP address, but when I add the domain name it does work or when I do a **dig  +search**

Why is the domain name a prerequisite for DIG to resolve the hostname to IP?

Answer (score 1):

Because `dig` is working as designed.

snip from man page:
       +[no]search
Use or do not use the search list defined by the search list or domain directive in the /etc/resolv.conf file (if any). The search list is not used by default.

In short, do not confuse `dig` with `nslookup`

Comment: I know it woks differently, but why is a domain even important for solution, can you explain that part to me?